# Blender 2.83, compatibility with files from older versions

Tags: versions, compatibility

This might be a silly question, but when opening a file from Blender 2.79 in Blender 2.81, the layout of the screen is different and some materials get messed up.

Does this or something like this occur when opening files from 2.81 in 2.83?
 I'm contemplating downloading the latest version and I'm in between projects and don't want it to mess up my workflow.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there wont any big issues like that when opening files from 2.81 in 2.83 but do note that any of your fluid simulations will not work properly as there was a new engine called mantaflow that was introduced in 2.82 and replaced the old engine.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Blender has advanced a lot. It used to be that it would run on very humble hardware. Not any more. Newer releases use newer hardware as well and maybe they won't run well at all on older machines. Keep in mind that when you save files in newer versions, they might not open again in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it (you can always have more versions of blender installed on the same computer). You only need some care about the liquid/smoke/fire simulations that have been updated recently.

Comment: My computer has the capability of an old microwave, every download is a big decision and a stressful one lol